# Running a process but permitting user action to stop it

Tags: python, multithreading, nested

I'm working on an automation system that allows you to select a process, but I want to continuously ping that process for status updates, but allowing the user to change other activities in the process.  This works if I run two py files simultaneously, but that's not very effective for complex situations.

In simplistic terms: I want to be able to switch between controlling different things, but still have live information.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this in a simple python file, or even in multiple ones running off the same application.

Example:

```
import time

def setHVACTemp():
    '''does stuff'''

def setHVACStatus():
    '''does stuff'''

def fetchTemp():
    print("72")

def fetchHum():
    print("65%")

def fetchFan():
    print("On")

def currentTemp():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        fetchTemp()

def currentHum():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        fetchHum()

def currentFan():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        fetchFan()


def menu():
    print("1. HVAC")
    print("2. TV")
    print("3. Other stuff")
    opt = input("Select your option: ")
    if opt == "1":
        print("a. Set Temp " + currentTemp() + " " + currentHum() + " " + currentFan)
        print("b. Set Home/Away")
        opt2 = input("Select HVAC Option: ")
        if opt2 == "a":
            setHVACTemp()
        if opt2 == "b":
            setHVACStatus()

menu()
```

How do I make it that this menu updates the temp/humidity/fan live (so every x seconds or so), but still allows the person to select 2 or 3 for the TV or Vacuum?  It just gets stuck on the while loop.

it does this:

```
1. HVAC
2. TV
3. Other stuff
Select your option 1
72
72
72
72
72
72
Process finished with exit code -1
```

I want it to do:

```
1. HVAC
2. TV
3. Other stuff
Select your option 1

a. Set Temp (75 65% On)
b. Set Home/Away (Home)
Select HVAC option:
```

I'm a beginner at Py (and coding in general), so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into multithreading? That may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks!  Threading was the trick.  Had a hard time initially finding examples that weren't overly complicated to help me implement, but found a solution!

Answer (score 1):

My example was poor, but I did find something that was a much simpler example that will work.

This produced "do other stuff", while the beeping continuously beeped.

```
import threading
import winsound


def worker():
    """thread worker function"""
    while True:
        winsound.MessageBeep(1)
        '''Just as a test I put a beeping noise in here'''

threads = []

def test():
    for i in range(1):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
        print("do other stuff")

test()
```

Source: https://pymotw.com/3/threading/